# Tab order in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer

I have complicated UI created with Qt Designer. It has a hierarchy of nested widgets. I need certain tab order to switch between controls inside these widgets. But as far as I see, Qt designer allows to define tab order only within one widget. How to do it globally?

Comment: look at this : [get-focus-or-tab-order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20154635/get-focus-or-tab-order)

Comment: and at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33760978/fix-tab-order-after-inserting-widgets-in-a-layout-in-qt/34051620

Comment: Are you saying that the component widgets do not have a self-contained tab order? So you want the tab order to jump between child widgets within different components? If so, there is no way to do this in Qt Designer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

open the **Edit** menu and select **Edit Tab Order**. In this mode, each input widget in the form is shown with a number indicating its position in the tab order. you can click on the box number and change the priority.by right click you can see 3 options, start from here, restart and Tab order list.